# My JFrame freezes when my Weighing Scale is off

Tags: java, swing, jframe

i have a java application and i am developing a scenario if my application would work if my weighing scale is off. But when i turned off my weighing scale my JFrame freezes is there a code for this error? here is the code 
the System freezes on line 4.

```
serialPort.openPort();//Open serial port
serialPort.setParams(9600, 8, 1, 0);//Set params.
serialPort.writeBytes("R".getBytes());
String a = serialPort.readString(13).trim();
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, it looks like you're doing this in the UI thread. You should basically avoid doing I/O in the UI thread, as it means that while the I/O is waiting, your UI will be unresponsive.

Instead, you should either use asynchronous I/O, or perform all the I/O in a separate thread, but remember to marshal any results back to the UI thread, as you shouldn't perform any UI work *not* on the UI thread. See the [Swing concurrency tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

As an aside, I'd *strongly* recommend against calling `getBytes()` without specifying an encoding - you really don't want to use the platform encoding. (In this case, I suspect you know the single byte you want to write, so I'd write that directly...)

Comment: Hi sir Jon thank you for the information. but my problem is at line 4. so sorry i am new in reading weighing scale. correct me if i'm wrong sir, line 4 waits for the User input. but what should id do to validate that my scale is off? thank you in advance. sorry for the grammar.

Comment: @BonjoBondad: Line 4 is waiting for the serial port, as far as I can tell. Presumably if the scales are off, that's never going to return - hence why your UI is freezing as I described. As for whether you need to handle any exceptions - well yes, you should handle I/O exceptions, but I can't really tell you what you should do with them. As for detecting that the scale is off - I don't know how easy that would be to do. I suggest you experiment using a simple console app as that's easier to mess with than a Swing UI. Are any exceptions being thrown? Are you sure you're succeeding in writing?

Comment: Thank you sir. I am trying some code for the exceptions. hope to know which one. :D thank you again. :)

Comment: Sir the line 4 don't throws exception and i am pretty sure that the code writes into the serial port. because once I run the program the serial adapter lights up. Meaning of some data is being write to the port. the thing is why the serial adapter don't response that the weighing scale don't give data for return.

Comment: @BonjoBondad: Well I can't tell you that, I'm afraid... but again, if you weren't in the UI thread, your UI wouldn't freeze.